# How to creat new ID's in new table with MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I've seen lots of questions with similar headlines or interest but different from what I am looking for.

I have a table with some data in it already, with an id column. I want the id's of the data already in the table, a couple thousand rows, to remain the same. I want to `INSERT` different data from another table, which also includes id's - just over 92,000 rows in this set -- and I need these id's to change to some other non-existing ID so as not to overwrite or displace the already existing data.

Is this possible? Is there some kind of increment I can do upon `INSERT`?

I tried an `INSERT IGNORE` statement but it displaced the data already there.

Any advice on what to try?

Comment: Please show the definition (schema) of your first table

Comment: Are you using auto-increment for the IDs?

Comment: Your ID column having primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `id` in your first table is an `auto_increment` column then you can just omit it

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (column2, column3, column4, ...) -- id is omitted
SELECT column2, column3, column4, ... -- id is also omitted
  FROM table2
```

If it's not the case, and assuming that it's a one-time operation, you can try to assign new ids in a following way

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, column2, column3, column4, ...)
SELECT t.max_id + s.id, s.column2, s.column3, s.column4, ...
  FROM
(
  SELECT @n := @n + 1 id, column1
    FROM table2 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0) i
   ORDER BY id
) s JOIN 
(
  SELECT MAX(id) max_id
    FROM table1
) t
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90120/1)** demo

Comment: Brilliant! Your first chunk of sql worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To start with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value other than 1, set that value with CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE, like this:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```